# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, android, file, sdk, external

I'm facing the problem of writing files to Android external storage here is my code:

```
public static File createFile(File path, String fileName) {
    Timber.d("%s%s", path.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
    if (path != null) {
        createDir(path);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "createFile path = " + path.getAbsolutePath() + " fileName = " + fileName);
        File file = new File(path, fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                if (file.createNewFile()) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The file was successfully created! - " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The file exist! - " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to create the file.", e);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File already exists!! Please rename file!");
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Renaming file");
            return createFile(path, "1" + fileName);
        }
        if (!file.canWrite()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "The file can not be written.");
        }
        return file;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static File createDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null) {
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            try {
                if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dirs are successfully created");
                    return dir;
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Dirs are NOT created! Please check permission write to external storage!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.e(e);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dir already exists");
            return dir;
        }
    }
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File is null or unable to create dirs");
    return null;
}
```

this is my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

I granted permission and added *android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"*
i have learned many different ways, i tried on android API < 29, it works fine, however i tried with API 32 i got the above error, hope anyone can help, thank you

Comment: 1. Which line of code throws the exception? 2. Please provide a [mcve]. In particular: there is more work you can do on your end to reduce the example - make it more minimal - does a function that creates a new File object with a hardcoded path in an existing directory and calls file.createNewFile() produce the same error?